# How many of $A\subseteq B$ are true for a set of $n$ elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let U be the set $\{1, ,2 ,...,n\}$. This set has $2^n$ subsets. So there are $2^n \cdot 2^n = 2^{2n}$ possible relations of the form $A\subseteq B$. I'm wondering how many of them are true.

Since $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set, at least $2^n$ are true. Since every set is a subset of itself, we got $2^n -1$ other inclusion. So the answer must be greater than $2^{n+1}-1$ but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you’re asking for is the number of ordered pairs $\langle A,B\rangle\in\wp(U)\times\wp(U)$ such that $A\subseteq B$. Each such pair divides $U$ into three pairwise disjoint sets, $A$, $B\setminus A$, and $U\setminus B$. Go through $U$ one element at a time, assigning it to one of these three sets, and you’ll have constructed such a pair; conversely, each such pair can be uniquely constructed in this fashion. In how many ways can you do that? I’ve left the answer in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Thus, there are $3^n$ such pairs.

Answer (score 3):

For $A$ the set of zero elements, there are $2^n$ possibilities for $B$.  For $A$ a set of $1$ element, there are $\binom{n}1$ possibilities for $A$ and $2^{n-1}$ possibilities for $B$.  ...

This leads to the sum:

$$\binom{n}0\cdot2^n+\binom{n}1\cdot2^{n-1}+\ldots+\binom{n}n\cdot2^0\;.$$

The sum is equal to $(2 + 1)^n = 3^n$.

Answer (score 2):

For each $k$ from $0$ to $n$, there are $\binom nk$ sets $B$ having $k$ elements, and each such $B$ has $2^k$ subsets $A$.  Thus the total is
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk 2^k = (1+2)^n = 3^n $$
by the binomial theorem.